# Wrong output trying to print a triangle

Tags: java

I tried to print a pattern

```
* * * * *
* * * * 
* * *
* *
*
```

I wrote this code in java

```
public class Psttr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner h=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=h.nextInt();
        int x=n;
        int i=1;
        
        for( i=1;i<=n;i++);
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=x;j++) {
                System.out.print("*");  
            }
            x=x-1;
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

I didn't get the right output, always `*****`

Expected output:

```
* * * * *
* * * * 
* * *
* *
*
```

Comment: `for( i=1;i<=n;i++);` that semicolon at the end shouldn't be there.

Comment: wow man, thanks, whats the difference?

Comment: `for` is followed either by a statement or by a block. While you may think you put a block after the `for`, the fact that you put a semicolon means that you just put an empty statement after it (you're doing nothing `n` times). Then the block gets executed only once because it's not part of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good, just get rid of the semicolon after the first cycle
so it would be:

```
public class Psttr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner h=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=h.nextInt();
        int x=n;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){ // You can init "i" here
            for(int j=1; j<=x--; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            x--; // You can use post-decrement (or pre, it's the same here)
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Also it seems you're quite new to programming so I added some little advice to write "better code"